# Parsing HTML - Only showing one item not the list

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

```
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string htmlPage = "";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
       //     htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://m.buses.co.uk/stop.aspx?stopid=6884");

     //htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.imdb.com/movies-in-theaters/");
     htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://m.buses.co.uk/destinations.aspx");

        }

        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);

        List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();
        foreach (var div in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class, 'menu')]"))
        {
            Movie newMovie = new Movie();
      //  newMovie.Cover = div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='image']//img").Attributes["src"].Value;
        //   newMovie.Title = div.SelectSingleNode(".//h4[@itemprop='name']").InnerText.Trim();
         // newMovie.Summary = div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='outline']").InnerText.Trim();
           //   newMovie.Summary = div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='services']").InnerText.Trim();

          newMovie.Summary = div.SelectSingleNode(".//a[starts-with(@href, 'place.aspx')]").InnerText.Trim();
            movies.Add(newMovie);
        }
        lstMovies.ItemsSource = movies;
    }
```

I am trying to get the list of Popular Destinations, the Names of the places, below is the part which I am interested in. I am able with the code above to get the first place - Amex Stadium. But it's not displaying anymore than that.

```
      <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1154">
            Amex Stadium
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1136">
            Brighton Marina
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=907">
            Brighton Station
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=910">
            Brighton University  Moulsecoomb
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=916">
            Churchill Square
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=918">
            Coldean
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=924">
            County Hospital
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=943">
            Eastbourne
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=957">
            George Street  Hove
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=965">
            Hangleton
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=972">
            Hollingbury
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=993">
            Lewes
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=997">
            Longhill School
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1006">
            Mile Oak
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1011">
            Newhaven
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1134">
            North Street
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1020">
            Old Steine
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1026">
            Patcham
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1028">
            Peacehaven
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1035">
            Portslade Station
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1042">
            Queens Park
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1047">
            Rottingdean
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1057">
            Seaford
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1062">
            Shoreham
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1135">
            St Peter's Church
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1074">
            Steyning
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1076">
            Sussex University
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1080">
            Tunbridge Wells
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1082">
            Uckfield
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1091">
            Westdene
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1092">
            Whitehawk
            </a>
           </li>

        <li>
            <a href="place.aspx?placeid=1095">
            Woodingdean
            </a>
           </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: It would help is you provided (a part of) the page you are interested in. And a clear explanation of what you tried, got and expected.

Comment: Sorry, Added more information now.

Comment: Please keep in mind that screen-scraping IMDB is not legal without their express written consent. From their [conditions of use](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_article?conditions): *You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below.*

Comment: @cory - it was just an example. I was using an example that was taking in the information form IMDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selections is wrong. The statement

```
SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class, 'menu')]")
```

only selects `<DIV class="menu">` and since there is only one such DIV you only get one place. You should change it to:

```
SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class, 'menu')]/ul/li")
```

and then use:

```
newMovie.Summary = div.SelectSingleNode("a[starts-with(@href, 'place.aspx')]").InnerText.Trim();
```

Notice, I removed `.//` from this latter selection.